# Implementing TypeScript into an existing Reactjs project learning TS and getting unknown errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, frontend, react-tsx

I am transitioning my vite Reactjs project over to TS and I am getting some errors that I am not sure about and cant seem to find a good answer on google to navigate.

Here are some of the errors I am not sure about and how I would set their types or go about them:

> Error: Type '{ dog: {}; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ dog: any; isSelected: any; onSelect: any; }': isSelected, onSelect

What it says the error is for:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getDogData, getMatch } from "../data/dogData";
import DogData from "./dog cards/DogData";
import { useAuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./dog cards/dogs.css";

function DogFound() {
  const [finalDog, setFinalDog] = useState({});
  const { selectedDogs } = useAuthContext();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    getMatch(selectedDogs).then((data) => {
      getDogData([data.match]).then((data) => {
        setFinalDog(data[0]);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="dog-found-container">
        <div>
          <h3>Congratulations!, You found a new family member</h3>
          <div className="dog-found">
            <DogData dog={finalDog} /> /// Error highlights DogData which is page component
          </div>

          <div className="go-home-button">
            <button onClick={() => navigate("/home")}>Go to Homepage</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DogFound;
```

```js
const AuthContext = createContext({
  loggedIn: false,
  setLoggedIn: (val: boolean) => {},
  selectedDogs: [] as string[],
  setDogMatch: (data: string[]) => {},
});

 const [selectedDogs, setSelectedDogs] = useState<string[]>([]);
 
  function setDogMatch(data: string[]) {
    setSelectedDogs(data);
    navigate("/dog-match");
  }
```

> Another Error: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'never'.

What its targeting:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const cities = [];
    selectedStates.forEach((state) =>
      cities.push(...getCityByState(state.value).map((city) => city.name)) // Error highlights everything inside cities.push
    );
    setCities(cities);
  }, [selectedStates]);
```

```js
 const [selectedStates, setSelectedStates] = useState([]);
  const [cities, setCities] = useState(getCities);
  
   const handleSelectedStates = (data) => {
    setSelectedStates(data);
  };
  
  <>
            <SearchFilters
              name="STATES"
              data={getStates}
              placeholder="All States"
              value={selectedStates}
              onChange={handleSelectedStates}
              isMulti
            />
          </>
          
  import { State, City } from "country-state-city";
import { Set_Options, Fetch_Api } from "./data";

export const getStates = State.getStatesOfCountry("US").map(
  (state) => state.isoCode
);

export const getCities = City.getCitiesOfCountry("US");

export const getCityByState = (state: string) => {
  return City.getCitiesOfState("US", state);
};

export const getLocation = async (states: string, city: string) => {
  const payload = {
    states: states,
    city: city,
  };
  return fetch(Fetch_Api + "/locations/search", <any>{
    ...Set_Options,
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      throw e;
    });
};

import Select from "react-select";

type Props = {
  data: (string | number)[];
  name: string;
};

export default function SearchFilters(props: Props) {
  const options =
    props.data &&
    props.data?.map((data) => {
      return { value: data, label: data };
    });

  return (
    <div className="dropdown-container">
      <h4>{props.name}</h4>
      <Select options={options} isSearchable={true} {...props} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Last error that is happening to quite a few of my components that I am passing data/value/options/place holders to:

> Type '{ name: string; data: number[]; value: { value: number; label: number; }[]; onChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction<{ value: number; label: number; }>>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
> Type '{ name: string; options: { value: string; label: string; }[]; value: { value: string; label: string; }[]; onChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction<{ value: string; label: string; }>>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
> Property 'options' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
> Type '{ name: string; data: never[]; placeholder: string; value: never[]; onChange: (data: any) => void; isMulti: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
> Property 'placeholder' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.

The Code:

```
<SearchFilters
            name="MIN AGE"
            data={Age_Menu}
            **value**={[minAge]} // Error highlights value
            onChange={setMinAge}
          />
          <SearchFilters
            name="MAX AGE"
            data={Age_Menu}
            **value**={[maxAge]} // Error highlights value
            onChange={setMaxAge}
          />
          {ageAlert && (
            <Alert
              variant="danger"
              onClose={() => setAgeAlert(false)}
              dismissible
            >
              <p>Maximum Age Cannot be less than Minimum Age</p>
            </Alert>
          )}
          <SearchFilters
            name="SORT BY"
            **options**={Sort} // Error highlights option
            value={[selectedSort]}
            onChange={setSelectedSort}
          />

          <>
            <SearchFilters
              name="BREEDS"
              data={dogBreeds} 
              placeholder="All Breeds"
              value={selectedBreeds}
              onChange={handleSelectedBreeds}
              isMulti
            />
          </>
          <>
            <SearchFilters
              name="STATES"
              data={getStates}
              **placeholder**="All States" // Error highlights placeholder
              value={selectedStates}
              onChange={handleSelectedStates}
              isMulti
            />
          </>
          <>
            <SearchFilters
              name="CITIES"
              **data**={cities} // Error highlights data
              placeholder="Select City"
              onChange={handleSelectedCity}
              isClearable={true}
            />
```

SearchFilters takes in both string arrays and numbers depending which search filter it is for.

I put the stuff in bold where it shows that I have an error.

I am not sure how I set the types or what the errors are for exactly and how to navigate them. Thanks for the help. Learning TypeScript as I go on this project.

I have tried googling the various errors trying to transition everything over and cant find a good answer without causing a new error or setting the wrong thing.

Comment: The first error happens because apparently `DogData` component expects `isSelected` and `onSelect` properties, but you don't pass any. Second error is because `selectedStates` is not properly typed and TS inferred its type as `never` which doesn't have any properties. I can't tell how to fix this because you didn't provide the declaration of `selectedStates`. The last one is because `SearchFilter` doesn't have a `placeholder` property.

Comment: To fix these you need to either add missing/delete unknown properties, or alter the type declarations of `DogData`, `SearchFilter` and `selectedStates` so that their types are what you expect them to be. How exactly, again,  I can't tell, because you didn't provide declarations of these, and I would also need a description of what types you want them to be

Comment: I havent yet set the types of those yet, because I wasnt sure of the error what they should be listed as completely.  The` SearchFilter` Component takes a strings of arrays and or  takes numbers  for the age. `selectedStates`, is a state object that takes in selected  states that are strings. `DogData` takes in a string of arrays of IDs and picks one at random. I will add more to my question above.

Comment: Describing what these variables/components do conceptually is not useful at the moment, you need to specify which types you want them to be. Like "`DogData` takes in a string of arrays of IDS and picks one at random" works as a description, but now you need to decide exactly how you want the interface of this component to look like. What is the name of the prop where the string of arrays is passed? Does it need other props like `isSelected` or whatever? This is want you need to formalize somewhat, then write type according to the interface you want your component to have

Comment: I see you did provide declaration for `selectedStates`, now I can tell: you just wrote `useState([])` but ts doesn't know which type are the elements of this array are supposed to have, so it just thinks `selectedStates` is array of `never`s. You need to hint TS which types will be in the array either with `useState<MyType[]>([])` (preferable) or `useState([] as MyType[])`.

Comment: For `SearchFilters` you didn't specify the `placeholder` prop in its `Props`. So TS doesn't know that `SearchFilter` accepts a `placeholder` prop, so it shouts at you when you try to use one. Add `placeholder?: string` to `Props` if you want it to be usable. And not only `placeholder`: you are also trying to use `value`, `onChange` and `isMulti`, which don't appear in declaration of `Props`. If you want to allow all props that `react-select` supports, this library probably exports a type for its props like `SelectProps`, and you can do `type Props = SelectProps & { /* your custom props */ }`

Comment: When I do set the props for `DogData` and `SearchFilter`  do I set those  `Prop types` inside their `DogData` and `SearchFilter` components or do i set their `Prop types` where I have those components placed now? Thank you for your help, I found your last response insightful.

Comment: You specify props that the component expects in the component definition. Components are not any different from regular functions. For functions you specify arguments' types when defining them, then everywhere you use them you must provide arguments that match these types. Same with component, except there is only one arguments `props` and it is an object type.